# FOR XML PATH carriage return for Excel

Tags: excel, xml, path

I am seeking .csv output from a SSMS (SQL Server 2014) query which concatenates values into one cell for Excel.  The code below puts semi-colon as delimiter, but I want to put in the carriage return for Excel so each value is on its own line within the cell.  (Right now I do this manually with Excel search for semi-colon and replace with CHAR(10)).
How can I alter this below to give string with carriage return in a text file for Excel instead of semicolon?
( I inherited this code, so I cannot explain it--  I just know it works now but I need to change it.)

---

```
SELECT effworkruleid, 
       REPLACE(Stuff((SELECT ', ' + zonename 
              FROM   _pcr_Zones1 
              WHERE  effworkruleid = T.effworkruleid 
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, ''), ',', ';')
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT effworkruleid 
        FROM   _pcr_Zones1) T
```

---

Answer (score 0):

How about the following SQL...

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (effworkruleid int, zonename VARCHAR(30));
INSERT   INTO @tbl (effworkruleid, zonename)
VALUES (333, 'g')
   ,(333 , 'f')
   ,(333 , 'y')
   ,(222 , 'x')
   ,(222 , 'y')
   ,(222 , 'z')
   ,(111 , 'E')
   ,(111 , 'F')
   ,(444 , 'L');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ','
    , @Lf CHAR(1) = CHAR(10);

SELECT DISTINCT c.effworkruleid
   , REPLACE(
        STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(@separator, CAST(zonename AS VARCHAR(30))) AS [text()]
        FROM @tbl AS O
        WHERE O.effworkruleid = C.effworkruleid 
        ORDER BY effworkruleid, zonename ASC
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, NULL), @separator, @Lf)
        AS zonename_List
FROM @tbl AS C;
```